# Replacing 'non-tagged' content in a web page

Tags: html, ios, regex, parsing

I'm currently looking at a method for replacing specific text within a web page, but I don't want to mess with anything that might be used as markup (i.e. HTML itself).  I've looked at a number of approaches including matching up '<' and '>' characters (and ignoring what's in between), but this unfortunately breaks when the web page is badly formed and they don't match up, or the content is poor, or there is an embedded '<' or '>' within the actual text.  It's also extremely slow.

Extracting specific text is not the objective.  Instead, I need to replace it with different text.

// Editing to make clearer (not sure why I got two -1s for this question).

1) Here is a very simple example

```
<head>
    <title>This is my website</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//a.b.c">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mystuff.ready(function () {    
            mystuff.using("snippets", function () {
                mystuff.snippets.initSnippetRenderer();
            });   
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body class="question-page new-topbar">
    <noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
    <div id="notify-container"></div>
    <h1>This is piece of large text</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

All you would expect to see in a browser when you open it is the following (let's call this **'text of interest'**):

```
This is a Large Piece of Text
* Coffee
* Tea
* Milk
```

The key thing I'm interested in therefore is how I determine what stuff is outside the tags (i.e. the text of interest and allow that to be searched and replaced using RegEX).

2). @Zaph - stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range is insufficient, because it's not straight forward to determine what the range is.  The range depends on whether the text is contained within an HTML tag, or is the payload operated on by the tag) - see point '1' above.

If I used a straight forward replace of the text 'website' for example, then it would replace the text in the title, but it would also mistakenly replace the term in the second meta tag, which is not OK.

Any ideas, or is there anything else I might think of that would intelligently work with the HTML payload rather than the supporting tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Supply sample input and output, and include special cases with these examples.

Comment: The method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` supports a Regular Expression with the option: `NSRegularExpressionSearch`. Keep in mind that "Look-ahead assertion", "Negative look-ahead assertion", "Look-behind assertion" and "Negative Look-behind assertion" can be very powerful. See: ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: I get the assertion approach.  I think it has its uses and might be selectively applied (e.g. don't match anything contained within <script ..</script>.  However, it seems that this might need a different tack.  Using pure RegEx seems like something that would be incredibly complex to use to cater for almost every tag.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Is this your html? If so then surround the text you want to replace with a div and add a tag to the div for matching purposes. Example: `<li><div tag=1>Milk</div></li>`

Comment: That's a good idea @Zaph, but the HTML is not mine and I have no control over it.  I need to assume that I will come up against badly formed pages and gracefully adapt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression with Look-behind and Look-ahead assertion.

The example replaces the matched text with itself but wrapped in evil emoji. The point is to demonstrate the matching pattern. Use `NSRegularExpression` for more control over the replacements.

Explanation:

`(?<=>)   Must be preceded with: >`
`\\S      Must start with a non-whitespace character (the \ has to be escaped)`
`[^<>]+   Must consist of characters except < and >`
`(?=</)   Must be followed by </`

```
NSString *html = <question html>;

NSString *pattern = @"(?<=>)\\S[^<>]+(?=</)";
NSString *replacement = @"$0";
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:pattern
                                       withString:replacement
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)]
NSLog(@"html:\n%@", html);
```

Output:

```
<head>
    <title>This is my website</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//a.b.c">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mystuff.ready(function () {    
            mystuff.using("snippets", function () {
                mystuff.snippets.initSnippetRenderer();
            });   
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body class="question-page new-topbar">
    <noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
    <div id="notify-container"></div>
    <h1>This is piece of large text</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```